# Ubuntu 16.04 Update

Tags: 14.10

I was wondering if anyone knew when my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop would upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 without having to do a clean install. I thought I had heard in July.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.10 will never upgrade to 16.04. Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported for a long time.